# Rasterize line polygons based on length fraction in cells

Tags: python, r, python-xarray, terra

I have a line vector dataset which I want to rasterize by summing the (numeric) values of my field of interest of all lines within a raster cell. Some lines intersect more than one raster cell. In order to avoid double-counting, the solution needs to be based on a weighted sum according to the length-fraction of each road in the raster cells it touches. For example, if a line has a field value of 5 and is split perfectly between raster cells A and B, this line should both add a value of 2.5 to both raster cells A and B's final summed value.
I saw that the R terra::rasterize() function accepts polygons, but does not perform the weighted sum which I want.

Is there any implementation in R or python that already implements this, or how could this be implemented?

Edit: Reproducable example, which shows that currently the raster values are added up from all lines that touch each raster cell.

```
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
l <- as.lines(v)

#give some numeric values  to the lines
l$values <- 1
l <- l[, 'values']
l <- project(l, '+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs')

#rasterize
dummy_raster <- rast(l, res = 20000)
l_rast <- rasterize(l, dummy_raster, field = 'values', fun = 'sum')

#plot
ggplot() +
    geom_spatraster(data = l_rast) +
    scale_fill_hypso_b() +
    geom_spatvector(data = l, aes(colour = as.factor(sample(seq_along(l)))), show.legend = F) +
    geom_spatvector_label(data = l, mapping = aes(label = values)) +
    NULL
```

[image: Summed up raster values from lines]

Comment: There are at least two ways to go forward: 1. rasterizing the lines and re-rastering A, B ... so that the new resolution is fine enough for counting line pixels per A, B ...; 2. polygonizing the raster A, B ... and intersecting/splitting the lines per polygons A, B ... and summarizing. (1) is raster operations, (2) is vector operations. (2) is more precise while (1) may be faster depending on your data. Regardless of preference, **please share an MRE**: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I've added an example. I would like to stick to raster operation if that is possible, since the actual dataset is pretty large.

Comment: After experimenting I found the vector variant "cleaner" in this case though. See suggested answer plz.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with vector operations:

[image: aggregate vector values by vector grid]

0. preparation:

```
    library(sf) ## mainly for vector operations
    library(dplyr)
    f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
```

1. read in shapefile, reproject, give each polygon a unit value for later weighting. Since dealing with a spatial dataframe, this weighting could be taken from any attribute (e. g. `POP`ulation):

```
    l <- st_read(f) |>
      st_transform(paste0('+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 ',
                          '+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs'
                          )
                   ) |>
      select(NAME = NAME_1,
             VALUE = 1 ## assume unity weight
             )
    
    ## Simple feature collection with 12 features and 2 fields
    ## Geometry type: POLYGON
    ## Dimension:     XY
    ## Bounding box:  xmin: 4015142 ymin: 2933827 xmax: 4071175 ymax: 3015403
    ## CRS:           +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
    ## First 10 features:
    ##            NAME VALUE                       geometry
    ## 1      Diekirch     1 POLYGON ((4037303 3014958, ...
    ## 2      Diekirch     1 POLYGON ((4046412 2980960, ...
    ## 3      Diekirch     1 POLYGON ((4025057 2981372, ...
    ## ...
```

2. create grid, make it a spatial dataframe (for later merging by cell number)

```
    dummy_grid <- 
      st_make_grid(l, cellsize = 2e4) |>
      st_as_sf() |>
      mutate(CELL_NO = row_number(), .before = 1)
```

3. intersect lines `l` with dummy grid, convert polygons to linestrings (so that length can be measured), compute weighted lengths, summarise by cell number:

```
    cell_aggregates <- 
      dummy_grid |>
      st_intersection(l) |>
      ## polygons to multilines to lines to compute length
      st_cast('MULTILINESTRING') |>
      st_cast('LINESTRING') |>
      mutate(WEIGHTED_LENGTH = st_length(x) * VALUE) |>
      ## drop geometry column:
      as.data.frame() |>
      summarise(WEIGHTED_LENGTH = sum(WEIGHTED_LENGTH), .by = CELL_NO)

    ## > cell_aggregates
    ##    CELL_NO WEIGHTED_LENGTH
    ## 1        8  286273.482 [m]
    ## 2       10   95999.155 [m]
    ## 3       11   86114.008 [m]
    ## 4       13    6092.423 [m]
```

4. merge calculated aggregates back to dummy grid:

```
    dummy_grid <- 
      dummy_grid |>
      left_join(cell_aggregates, by = 'CELL_NO')
```

5. examine:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    
    ggplot() + 
      geom_sf(data = dummy_grid,
              aes(fill = as.integer(WEIGHTED_LENGTH)),
              alpha = .5
              ) +
      geom_sf(data = l, alpha = 0, col = 'white') +
      geom_sf_text(data = dummy_grid, 
                    aes(label = sprintf('cell no. %s\n%.0f km', CELL_NO, WEIGHTED_LENGTH/1000))
                    ) +
      theme_void()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that answer! I see that the vector operation maybe the best way to go here. One issue I still struggle with is the weighting though. As I tried to explain above, the raster cells' final value should add up exactly to the sum of the values of the lines (spatial disaggregation). The disaggregation needs to be weighted by the line length inside the cells. I think in the current solution, this is not the case. Do you know a way how to adjust this?

Comment: I'm sorry. Do you mean line lengths per cell should be not absolute but relative to sum up to an arbitrary value, say, 100 %? Put differenty, if cell A has 15 km lines and cell B has 50 km lines, what values should be given to A and B?